# Add mutated results from for/in loop to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm mutating results from a NSArray: I'm replacing phone numbers without a country code prefix into one that do have a country code prefix. In some cases however, there might exist a case in which a person has two phone records. I need these two to stick together and after I've added the prefix, I need to put it into an array so that I get a sort of array that looks like this: `@[ @[@"0634343", @"4390493"], @[@"490209"]];` etc.

Currently I'm just creating an array that looks like this:

```
@[@"0634343", @"4390493", @"490209"];
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
     self.prefixSearchNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray *phoneNumbers in _phoneSearchResult) {
        NSMutableArray *formattedPhoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *phoneNumber in phoneNumbers) {
            NSString *firstChar = [phoneNumber substringToIndex:1];
            if (([firstChar isEqualToString:@"0"] && prefix != nil) || (firstChar == 0 && prefix!=nil)) {
               NSString *phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:prefix]; // trows warning: varibale 'phoneNumber' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization
                NSLog(@"phoneNumber: %@", phoneNumber); //returns phoneNumber withous prefix in Array;

            }
            [formattedPhoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
            NSLog(@"formattedPhoneNumbers: %@", formattedPhoneNumbers);
        }
        [self.prefixSearchNumbers addObject:formattedPhoneNumbers];
        name = [self.modifiedNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

How do I create the array with arrays?

Comment: a string of for instance `@"+31"`

Comment: Then lose `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", prefix]`.  That's just an expensive way to copy a string, and you don't need to copy it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to group your results by your index clones?

```
self.prefixSearchNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSArray *phoneNumbers in _phoneSearchResult) {
    NSMutableArray *formattedPhoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *phoneNumber in phoneNumbers) {
        NSString *firstChar = [phoneNumber substringToIndex:1];
        if (([firstChar isEqualToString:@"0"] && prefix != nil) || (firstChar == 0 && prefix!=nil)) {
            phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:prefix];
        }
        [formattedPhoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
    }
    [self.prefixSearchNumbers addObject:formattedPhoneNumbers];
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this returns nil

Comment: @bdv What returns nil? Why isn't it working for you?

Comment: `self.prefixSerachNubmers` returns nil. This has probably something to do with an array which memory isn't allocated yet. Figuring it out right now. Also the prefix isn't added..

Comment: @bdv Did you forget the first line? `self.prefixSearchNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: nope, but I don't think that's it. See, if I log `phoneNumber`, it returns nil too. Must have something to do with that too.

Comment: Update your question with the code as you currently have it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57533/discussion-between-bdv-and-crimsonchris).